# Get User Info from Google Api Using Azure Mobile Services for Xamarin Android

Tags: azure, xamarin.android, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I used Windows Azure Mobile Services for Xamarin Android to authenticate the User for Google and obtained the Authentication Token as

```
while(_currentUser == null){
_currentUser = await _mobileClient.LoginAsync(context, 
 MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google);
}

var authToken = _currentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken;

var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + authToken;
var request = WebRequest.Create (url)
var response = request.GetResponse ();
```

I get an an HTTP 401 Error : Unauthorized.
I want to get the User Info using this auth token. Is the auth token being returned from the Azure Mobile Services not fit for this purpose? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token returned by `LoginAsync` is an *Azure Mobile Service* token, not a Google token. If you want to get the access token to be able to talk to the google API, you actually need to go to the server side and retrieve the information at that point, via the [user object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554220.aspx) passed to the scripts.

The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/10/25/getting-user-information-on-azure-mobile-services.aspx has more information on how to get that access token.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to retrieve the information using the Azure Mobile Service token from the client side? (Server side implementation and scripts aren't under my control.)

Comment: Not at this moment. Feel free to log a feature request under https://mobileservices.uservoice.com/, which the team uses when planning the next features to add to the framework.