# Attempt to reuse auth token to connect xamarin app to azure fails

Tags: authentication, azure, xamarin

This initial login succeeds:

```
public static MobileServiceClient MOBILE = new MobileServiceClient("https://myapp.azure-mobile.net/",myApplicationKey);
MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider GOOGLEPROVIDER = MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google;

private async Task Connect() {
    var USER = await MOBILE.LoginAsync(this, GOOGLEPROVIDER);
    var CACHE = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "token", USER.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken } };
    var ACCOUNT = new Account(USER.UserId, CACHE);
    var STORE = AccountStore.Create(this);
    STORE.Save(ACCOUNT, "Google");
}
```

but then this attempt to reuse the token to reconnect without a login page fails:

```
public async Task Reconnect() {
    var STORE = AccountStore.Create(this);
    var token = STORE.FindAccountsForService("Google").ToArray()[0].Properties["token"];
    // token seems ok
    var jsonToken = new JObject();
    jsonToken.Add("access_token", token);
    var USER = await MOBILE.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google, jsonToken); // BOOM!
}
```

... with the following message:  "The POST Google login request must contain both code and id_token in the body of the request."

What I am getting wrong here?

Comment: While I'd still love to know why this broken, I seem to have overcomplicated the problem.  var xu = getXamarinUser(); MOBILE.CurrentUser = new MobileServiceUser(xu.Username);              MOBILE.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = xu.Properties["token"]; works well enough for reconnecting.

Answer (score 1):

The token you use in the code, viz.
    var CACHE = new Dictionary { { "token",USER.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken } };

The MobileServiceAuthenticationToken above is a token specific to MobileServices and cannot be used in the LoginAsync method (LoginAsync method requires a Google OAuth token.)

Please see this [Get User Info from Google Api Using Azure Mobile Services for Xamarin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591853/get-user-info-from-google-api-using-azure-mobile-services-for-xamarin-android)

Comment: Code parameter value is a part of the request. I did this a long time ago so I can't properly recall. Although, you won't be needing the code parameter value.